# Mathematica returns zero for small rational number to 1/133 power but not zero

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

This small number raised to the 1/133 root is not zero but Mathematica is underflowing with the computation.  I assume Mathematica is first computing the quotient numerically, then taking the root:

```
test = (2/
   6646800085981540557736151277427154103843320720309976808783804129181\
5845031522477461201260957183317111518099766191803900766434260643426826\
4818778165833278707908380046956481905711274190477612295313163535808285\
2180550329146770088876403201601191901299339149502981696765123881193775\
255836916500322459063124150067147954702849073520585)

test^(1/133) // N
```

[image]

However, if I extract the the numerator and denominator separately then take the root and form the quotient, I get the right answer:

```
nVal = Numerator@test;
dVal = Denominator@test;
n1 = nVal^(1/133) // N
n2 = dVal^(1/133) // N
n1/n2

0.00344692
```

Is there a way to compute the numerical value of test directly without going through these steps?

Comment: Use arbitrary precision with a specified number of digits of precision, e.g. `N[test^(1/133), 16]` .

Comment: Works fine for me on MA11.1

Comment: Thanks MarcoB.  That works!